# How to get access to data from Provider if class do not have context?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `Provider` as state manager. I have few widgets that collect data. One of my widget is button that should to complete saving of all data. It have `onPressed () { ... }` event. I would like to do some computation of data before saving.

I thought to do it in separate class:

```
class ResultProcessing 
{
    // here I need access to data from provider
}
```

Button:

```
  Flexible(
    child: Container(
       child: RaisedButton(
       child: Text("Save"),
       onPressed: () {
       // I need to pass data to ResultProcessing 
       },
     )),
   ),
```

But the problem that I can't get access to data in `Provider`, because `ResultProcessing` class is not widget and have not `context`.

The class name data from which I need to grab from my processing class is `Provider.of<AppState>(context).customer;`

And in which moment I should to create instance of `ResultProcessing`? In `onPressed` event?

Comment: You need to use a `ProxyProvider` and feed the provider which has data to `ResultProcessing`. If you can provide a bit more code (more class names) I'll write a small example.

Comment: @JulienLachal I have added a little bit more code.

Comment: well, in your `Flexible` you have access to `context`. Why can't you pass data to `ResultProcessing`?

Comment: @JulienLachal how `ResultProcessing resultProcessing = ResultProcessing(Provider.of<AppState>(context).customer);` ? And how to handle data in class?

Comment: it's still not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to pass data from widget to stand-alone class that have not `context` and do some processing inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, that's anti pattern. 
Your objects are *purposefully* not accessible outside of the widget tree.

You should change your approach. Instead, use widgets to act like a bridge between your model and your providers.

A typical example is `ProxyProvider` and similar variants

Comment: Could you provider any example?

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov I can't. Not with a better explanation of your use-case. This is specific to what you do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
Flexible(
  child: Container(
   child: RaisedButton(
     child: Text("Save"),
     onPressed: () {
       DataClass data = Provider.of<DataClass>(context); 
       // Pass data to ResultProcessing
       ResultProcessing.handle(data);
     },
   ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: thanks! Is it good practice? Or this approach have some minuses?

Comment: At least it separate the widget tree and your `ResultProcessing`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on a simple way. Add a required parameter to your class with a constructor and use it in the class, and then, send data from the widget where you have a build method(context) and access to the Provider.

```
class ResultProcessing {
    String data; // add a parameter
    ResultProcessing({required this.data}); // add the constructor
    {
        //use the data here as you want
    }
}
```